# Why can not create a component with this prop called value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

The statement of my component is: only i want to pass as props value and onChange, but when i used i never got the value in the console.log

```
const CardSelect = ({ value, onChange }) => {
console.log('Value', value) // value is null
...
}
```

there is something to dont allow to named like a 'value' as a component property ?

i am using like this: i am passing value and onChange but i sure dont know what is happening please help.

```
<CardSelect value='this is the value' onChange={()=>{console.log('fn')}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/lively-shadow-ztx56m?file=/src/App.js. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: this is not a answer